# Working together in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

is there any way to work with someone else together on a shared document on visual studio something like google docs?
I tried to make it using the shared project on visal studio but I didn't work

Comment: Sure, there are many ways to work together with multiple developers. Look at the [Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) for example.

Comment: I know this service but I don't how to use it, can you explain it to me?